# Content doesn't change after v-model is updated from dropdown Froala Editor VueJs

Tags: vuejs3, froala

My requirement is to bind text to Froala Editor based on dropdown value.

I set value to v-model.

```
<Carevender-Editor :dataValue="model.csContent" ref="froalaEditor"></Carevender-Editor>
```

I set immediateVueModelUpdate to true but it doesn't work.

```
config: {
          immediateVueModelUpdate:true,
}
```

I want to update content in editor after selecting dropdown.
But now v-model doesn't update.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it.
I add function in Froala editor component to set value for model.

```
methods:{
   setValue(value){
     this.model = value;
   }
}
```

I add ref for editor component in other components

```
<Carevender-Editor @getText="getEditorValue" :dataValue="templatebody" ref="froalaEditor"></Carevender-Editor>
```

And then in dropdown selected change event,
I call that ref with value.

```
selectedTemplate(value) {
          var tem = this.templates.filter(x => x.oid == value)[0];
          this.templatebody = tem.body;
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.isViewMode = false;
          }, 200);
      }
```